# What is the answer to this probability question?

Tags: probability

In a country  there are $\dfrac{12}{1000}$ males who are diagnosed with diabetes. Out of those males $\dfrac8{10}$ are diagnosed with positive results.

What is the probability of man who is diagnosed with diabetes and has positive test results?

Comment: Firstly, what do you think and how did you get there>

Comment: Please edit your question with your attempt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we have $1000$ men, then $12$ of these are diagnosed with diabetes.

Out of those males, $\frac8{10}$ have positive results, that is $9.6$ men.

Therefore, $9.6$ in every $1000$ men fits the criteria, which is a probability of $0.0096$, or $0.96\%$